# Ocs Inventory no funciona

Tags: c#, windows

Bueno no se si pueda hacer esto pero ya mucho tiempo llevo intentando instalar el Ocs Inventory server en el servidor de la empresa que tiene windows server 2008 me fue imposible por diferentes motivos como problemas de puertos seguridad y configuraciones que tenia el mismo servidor lo que busco es sencillo es hacer un inventario de los equipos de la empresa, tener un cliente o agente que haga el escaneo de la pc y lo mande al servidor intente desatollar uno pero me dijeron que lo querían todo en automático lo que no se es como sacar la licencia de windows solo se usar un poco C# he intentado usar también GLPI con Ocs y tampoco pude si alguien me podría recomendar algún programa o a orientarme a hacerlo en C# estaré eternamente agradecido estarían ayudando a un Becario en apuros.
Si este post inflige normas borrenlo no hay problem

Comment: Puedes instalar xampp o wampp en un equipo cualquiera dentro de la red y desde allí instalas OCS Inventory. Ese equipo actuaría como tu servidor virtual.

Comment: de echo en la lap que me dieron en la empresa si me salio, a las computadores que le instale el cliente se conectas solas cuando las prenden, me pregunto si podría hacer un usuario en windows 10 y que el encargado se conecte y vea el inventario y seguir usando la computadora sin tener que prestárselas o dejar de hacer lo que estoy haciendo para pesarle algún dato?

Comment: Si está implementado en un servidor (como xampp, wampp o lampp) debería permitir el acceso vía web. En la barra de dirección del navegador web pon http://nombre_o_ip_del_servidor/ocsreports/ debería solicitar nombre de usuario y contraseña.

Comment: si lo tengo en xampp 2.2 que es la versión con la que viene el software de ocs nada mas seria que este corriendo el xampp en mi equipo y ya los demás podrían entrar verdad?

Comment: Es correcto, entran por el navegador web con sus credenciales de usuario de OCS.

Comment: Amigo le agradezco mucho su tiempo y respuesta les di la opción que tenia y me dijeron que no les servia solo lo querían en el servidor ahora tendré que buscar otra opción para poner en mis practicas una lastima pero aprecio mucho su tiempo y una disculpa por hacerle perder su tiempo Gracias!

Comment: Pues termine mis practicas amigo y cambien de proyecto a Documentación de la red un gusto que me ayudara se lo agradeceré mucho no sirvió lo que hice de mucho con el otro proyecto pero si he aprendido mucho